# Cisco AIR-SAP2600 series AP random reboot

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, aironet, cisco-wireless

Our office seems to have started experiencing an issue where every 2-3 days our AIR-SAP2602 reboots then returns to normal function within ~2mins. I've checked the power source, made sure it's all stable, and all seems OK. Issue being once it reboots we lose the logs of course so I'm not able to see any errors it has thrown before the issue.

Currently attempting to set up SNMP (probably should have it already) to see if I can catch some messages before it reboots but I'm concerned that it might never send the messages since the period between it becoming unresponsive and rebooting is seemingly nonexistent.

I've followed through [Hardware Troubleshooting for the Cisco 2600 series](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/2600-series-multiservice-platforms/16138-hwts-2600-16138.html#reboot) but haven't been able to find anything. `show version` states system returned to ROM by power-on so no hints there, and there doesn't seem to be any bus errors either.

Anyone seen this before and might know what to look for?

EDIT: Set syslog trap to 5 and then waited until it rebooted, nothing came through on the syslog server but then ran **sh logging** as soon as it brought the interfaces back up and got the below:

Log Buffer (1048576 bytes):

> *Mar  1 00:00:09.975: %IFMGR-7-NO_IFINDEX_FILE: Unable to open nvram:/ifIndex-table No such file or directory
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:10.059: %SOAP_FIPS-2-SELF_TEST_IOS_SUCCESS: IOS crypto FIPS self test passed
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:17.127: %SOAP_FIPS-2-SELF_TEST_RAD_SUCCESS: RADIO crypto FIPS self test passed on interface Dot11Radio 0
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:23.383: %SOAP_FIPS-2-SELF_TEST_RAD_SUCCESS: RADIO crypto FIPS self test passed on interface Dot11Radio 1
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:25.535: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet0, changed state to up
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %SYS-6-CLOCKUPDATE: System clock has been updated from 00:00:25 UTC Mon Mar 1 1993 to 11:00:25 +1100 Mon Mar 1 1993, configured from console by console.
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from memory by console
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:25.815: Starting Ethernet promiscuous mode
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %SYS-5-RESTART: System restarted --
>   Cisco IOS Software, C3600 Software (AP3G2-K9W7-M), Version 15.2(2)JA, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
>   Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
>   Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
>   Compiled Thu 23-Aug-12 02:59 by prod_rel_team
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %SNMP-5-COLDSTART: SNMP agent on host AP1 is undergoing a cold start
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %CDP_PD-4-POWER_OK: Full power - HIGH_POWER inline power source
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %SYS-6-LOGGINGHOST_STARTSTOP: Logging to host 192.168.0.48 port 514 started - CLI initiated
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to reset
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:25: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to reset
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:26: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0, changed state to down
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:26: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Loopback0, changed state to up
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:26: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:26: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to down
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:26: %DOT11-6-FREQ_SCAN: Interface Dot11Radio0, Scanning frequencies for 16 seconds
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:27: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface BVI1, changed state to down
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:27: %DOT11-4-NO_HT: Interface Dot11Radio1, Mcs rates disabled on vlan 20 due to not using AES encryption or encryption is not disabled
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:28: %SOAP_FIPS-2-SELF_TEST_HW_SUCCESS: HW crypto FIPS self test passed
>
> *Mar  1 00:00:28.815: DPAA Initialization Complete
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:28: %SYS-3-HARIKARI: Process DPAA INIT top-level routine exited
>
> *Mar  1 11:00:29: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0, changed state to up

Comment: SNMP traps are a good start, but might prove futile if it is, indeed, random.  You might want to consider an external syslog facility to document everything that's happening leading up to it; not sure if a trap will go through if it's a sporadic reboot.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a hardware problem.  Do you have Smartnet for that device?

Comment: The "system returned to ROM by power-on" is showing you that there is indeed a power issue. Like Ryan Foley suggested, an external log server such as KIWI could prove to confirm a power problem.

Comment: I see, I'm setting up KIWI now for it. Will monitor it today, hopefully the issue shows up, and will report back

Comment: Added logging data from the AP dumped directly after an intermittent restart

Comment: Just for good measure, did you connect the access point directly to the switch with a known good patch cord? Does the same thing happen when you use an external power supply? Try another switch port too, maybe the one it's connect to right now might be faulty, have you checked the switch logs? The AP is reporting CDP_PD-4-POWER_OK, which indicates the switch is most likely also a Cisco switch, so it should be able to tell you a lot. Check for interface errors on the specific switchport too.

Comment: @RedShift I'm suspecting an environmental issue by now, since posting I've seen the reboot maybe once a month. It's connected to a non-PoE Cisco SG200 and running off external power.